# How to set order for constraints to be checked in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 2 constrains like below.

```
ALTER TABLE entity_instance ADD CONSTRAINT instance_name_uniq UNIQUE (tenant_id, name)

ALTER TABLE entity_instance ADD CONSTRAINT instance_source_uniq UNIQUE (tenant_id,source_key)
```

How can I make it mandatory that `instance_source_uniq` is checked first?

Comment: Is your question only about PostgreSQL? If so, remove the sql-server tag, which denotes Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Removed the tag!

Comment: Also, you may want to add to your question why the order of constraint validation matters for you use case. Generally, relational databases are set based so order does not matter.

Comment: @Dan: Order does not matter *logically*. Often still matters for performance. I agree with your request for details in any case. Postgres version and minimal table definition are generally instrumental as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to imagine a use case where it matters. Maybe a case where one constraint is *much* more likely to fail and/or the other one(s) are expensive (huge tables?) and you'd rather check the one first to optimize performance? Be that as it may, to answer the question asked:

`CHECK` constraints are applied *alphabetically*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> When a table has multiple `CHECK` constraints, they will be tested for each row in alphabetical order by name, after checking `NOT NULL` constraints.

But there is no such rule for `UNIQUE` constraints.

#### Slow and sure

A slow and sure way: define competing constraints as `DEFERRABLE`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> A constraint that is not deferrable will be checked immediately after every command. Checking of constraints that are deferrable can be postponed until the end of the transaction ...

But if the purpose of this is to optimize performance, this may defy the purpose. [The manual warns:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-COMPATIBILITY)

> Be aware that this can be significantly slower than immediate uniqueness checking.

There are also a couple of side effects. Like: `FK` constraints cannot currently point columns with only a deferrable `UNIQUE` constraint. Read the manual carefully. Related:

- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10032272/939860)

#### Quick and dirty

Some quick tests indicate that `UNIQUE` constraints are checked in the order of their creation. Could be bound to the `oid` in `pg_constraint` or the `oid` of the underlying unique index ... But neither can I give any guarantees that this is true, nor does the Postgres project guarantee anything in that direction. I found nothing in the manual or anywhere. Looks like an implementation detail that's **not reliable**. But for the sole purpose of performance optimization "not reliable" may still be good enough.

To take advantage of this observation create `instance_source_uniq` *before* you create `instance_name_uniq`. (`DROP` and recreate other `UNIQUE` constraints that were created earlier.) Check success with a forged `INSERT` that violates all competing `UNIQUE` constraints at once. You'll see an error message for the one that's checked first.

To further keep that order intact across dump / restore cycles, rename `instance_source_uniq` to something like `instance_1st_source_uniq`, which sorts before all other competing constraint names. `pg_dump` dumps objects in alphabetical order, so this should result in your favored constraint being created first on restore.

- [Postgres pg_dump dumps database in a different order every time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179376/939860) (Peter Eisentraut is a core developer.)

Again, no guarantees. Whenever `instance_1st_source_uniq` is dropped and recreated, you may lose the effect. Or if Postgres decides to do things differently. Or if there are exception to the observed behavior.